# Twin primes whose sum is a cube

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$84537841287167$ and $84537841287169$ are a pair of twin primes.

The sum of $84537841287167+84537841287169$ is a cube.

Are there other examples of twin pairs $p$, $p+2$ whose sum is a cube?

Have they to have a particular form?

Comment: @Peter could you find other examples?

Comment: What do you want to do with other examples?

Comment: For $k \le 10000$, there are $185$ values of $k$ where $p = 108k^3-1$ and $p+2$ are twin primes that sum to a cube. Following are some examples..
$107,2634011,29659499,57395627,104792291,271669247,485149499,\cdots\\
83797007573051, \color{red}{84537841287167},
88875400155587,89731703685707,89846291353499,\cdots$

Comment: @achillehui Can you post the program, please? I think it's very fast!

Comment: @taritgoswami it is a single line command using the CAS maxima `for k : 1 thru 10000 do if (primep(108*k^3-1) and primep(108*k^3+1)) then print(k," ",108*k^3-1);`

Comment: http://oeis.org/A061308 is worth a look.

Comment: similarly https://oeis.org/A240169

Comment: The first thought that came into my head was (3,5). Not a very general answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 22):

**List of Some Twin Primes Greater than $\bf{3}$ whose Sum is a Cube**

The sum of twin primes $6k-1$ and $6k+1$ is $12k$ and $12k=j^3\implies6\mid j$. So to look for such twin primes, look for twin primes of the form 
$$
(108n^3-1,108n^3+1)
$$
We can skip $n\equiv2\pmod5$ since
$$
\begin{align}
108\cdot n^3+1
&\equiv3\cdot2^3+1&\pmod5\\
&\equiv0&\pmod5
\end{align}
$$
and we can skip $n\equiv3\pmod5$ since
$$
\begin{align}
108\cdot n^3-1
&\equiv3\cdot3^3-1&\pmod5\\
&\equiv0&\pmod5
\end{align}
$$
Checking $n\equiv0,1,4\pmod5$, we get
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
n&108n^3-1&108n^3+1\\\hline
1&107&109\\
29&2634011&2634013\\
65&29659499&29659501\\
81&57395627&57395629\\
99&104792291&104792293\\
136&271669247&271669249\\
165&485149499&485149501\\
174&568946591&568946593\\
176&588791807&588791809\\
191&752530067&752530069\\
200&863999999&864000001\\
266&2032678367&2032678369\\
295&2772616499&2772616501\\
301&2945257307&2945257309\\
319&3505869971&3505869973\\
346&4473547487&4473547489\\
351&4670303507&4670303509\\
370&5470523999&5470524001\\
400&6911999999&6912000001\\
411&7498065347&7498065349\\
431&8646803027&8646803029\\
434&8828622431&8828622433\\
436&8951240447&8951240449\\
456&10240432127&10240432129\\
491&12784043267&12784043269\\
494&13019808671&13019808673\\
526&15717410207&15717410209\\
541&17100765467&17100765469\\
599&23211554291&23211554293\\
651&29796600707&29796600709\\
676&33362903807&33362903809\\
714&39311389151&39311389153\\
746&44837381087&44837381089\\
790&53248211999&53248212001\\
924&85200014591&85200014593\\
956&94362064127&94362064129\\
991&105110165267&105110165269\\
\end{array}
$$
Note that the sum of the primes is $(6n)^3$.

This list does not include $3+5=2^3$ because $(3,5)$ is the only twin prime that is not of the form $(6k-1,6k+1)$; that is, all primes greater than $3$ must be relatively prime to $6$.

---

**Mathematica Code**

```
Module[{s = "", m}, 
 For[n = 1, n < 1000, ++n, 
  If[MemberQ[{0, 1, 4}, Mod[n, 5]] && PrimeQ[(m = 108 n^3) - 1] && 
    PrimeQ[m + 1], 
   s = StringJoin[s, 
     ToString[n] <> "&" <> ToString[m - 1] <> "&" <> ToString[m + 1] <>
       "\\\n"]]]; s]
```

Comment: "We can immediately skip $n\equiv2,3\pmod5$ since $5\mid108\cdot2^3+1$ and $5\mid108\cdot3^3-1$"

I don't understand this line, could you explain this a little further?

Comment: As $5$ divides $108\cdot 2^3+1$, for any $k$ of the form $5t+2$ we have $108\cdot (5t+2)^3+ 1$. Now using binomial expansion you can see that it will left $5\cdot m+108\cdot 2^3$, which is divisible by $5$. Hence it can't be prime. So we are not checking for that $n$. Same argument goes for $n\equiv 3\pmod{5}$.

Comment: @spyr03: I have expanded the section about the values skipped

Answer (score 14):

$3$ and $5$ add to $2^3$, and $107 + 109 = 6^3$. So yes, there are other examples.

Clearly the sum has to be even, so if you want to systematically look for examples, then you could look through numbers of the form
$$
\frac{(2n)^3}{2}\pm 1
$$
and check whether they are twin primes. That's how I found the $6^3$ one, at least. I'm sure there are clever ways to cut down the search space further. Or maybe it's better to look through all twin primes and see whether they add to cubes. I have no idea which would actually be faster.

---

**Edit** Apart from $3+5$, the primes cannot be divisible by $3$ (obviously), and since neither $p$ nor $p+2$ are divisible by $3$, that means their sum *is* divisible by $3$. So instead of just $\frac{(2n)^3}2\pm1$, you can narrow it to $\frac{(6n)^3}2\pm 1$.

Once can do a similar analysis on the basis of, say, $5$, and find that $n\not\equiv 2, 3\pmod 5$, meaning the numerator must be on one of the forms $(30n)^3, (30n + 6)^3$ or $(30n + 24)^3$.

---

**New edit:**

I used my above idea to search with the following Python program:

```
import math 

def is_prime(n):
    if(n%2==0):
        return False
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):
        if(n%i==0):
            return False
    return True

for i in range(1,300):
    for k in [30*i, 30*i + 6, 30*i + 24]:           
        if is_prime(k**3/2 - 1) & is_prime(k**3/2 + 1):
            print "%d & %d & %d\\\\" % (k**3/2 - 1, k**3/2 + 1, k)
```

(The speed of the program starts to go down at about 300.)

It found the following list:
$$
\begin{array}{|cc|c|}
\hline
p&p+2&\sqrt[3]{\text{sum}}\\
\hline
2634011 & 2634013 & 174\\
29659499 & 29659501 & 390\\
57395627 & 57395629 & 486\\
104792291 & 104792293 & 594\\
271669247 & 271669249 & 816\\
485149499 & 485149501 & 990\\
568946591 & 568946593 & 1044\\
588791807 & 588791809 & 1056\\
752530067 & 752530069 & 1146\\
863999999 & 864000001 & 1200\\
2032678367 & 2032678369 & 1596\\
2772616499 & 2772616501 & 1770\\
2945257307 & 2945257309 & 1806\\
3505869971 & 3505869973 & 1914\\
4473547487 & 4473547489 & 2076\\
4670303507 & 4670303509 & 2106\\
5470523999 & 5470524001 & 2220\\
6911999999 & 6912000001 & 2400\\
7498065347 & 7498065349 & 2466\\
8646803027 & 8646803029 & 2586\\
8828622431 & 8828622433 & 2604\\
8951240447 & 8951240449 & 2616\\
10240432127 & 10240432129 & 2736\\
12784043267 & 12784043269 & 2946\\
13019808671 & 13019808673 & 2964\\
15717410207 & 15717410209 & 3156\\
17100765467 & 17100765469 & 3246\\
23211554291 & 23211554293 & 3594\\
29796600707 & 29796600709 & 3906\\
33362903807 & 33362903809 & 4056\\
39311389151 & 39311389153 & 4284\\
44837381087 & 44837381089 & 4476\\
53248211999 & 53248212001 & 4740\\
85200014591 & 85200014593 & 5544\\
94362064127 & 94362064129 & 5736\\
105110165267 & 105110165269 & 5946\\
111603347747 & 111603347749 & 6066\\
156246957827 & 156246957829 & 6786\\
169013118347 & 169013118349 & 6966\\
183838613471 & 183838613473 & 7164\\
215526633731 & 215526633733 & 7554\\
223322272991 & 223322272993 & 7644\\
226492415999 & 226492416001 & 7680\\
239472986111 & 239472986113 & 7824\\
280145695391 & 280145695393 & 8244\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
This skips $2^3 = 3+5$ and $6^3 = 107+109$, and $24^3 = 6911 + 6913$ (although $6913 = 31\cdot 223$, so that's irrelevant), because of some hiccup with the `range` in the primality test that I didn't bother fixing. Thanks to @taritgoswami for the prime test I copy-pasted from him and trimmed down a little. It still thinks $2$ is non-prime, but that's OK in this case. In fact, I could theoretically have taken away the whole parity check there, since I know I'm only feeding it odd numbers.

The print statement is formatted like that so that I could copy-paste it directly from the Python output into a MathJaX `array` without having to manually type all the formatting necessary.

Comment: some bigger one

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a cube, see the question body.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm sure we can. $17+19 = 6^2$, so $6$ is really prolific here.

Comment: with Maple can you find other examples?

Comment: @pantareis I'm sure I could. If I knew how to use Maple. Or you could do it: I've already told you one possible algorithm.

Comment: @pantareis I have used Python, see my answer. You can check it on repl.it online, in case Python is not installed.

Comment: @pantareis I found a bunch of examples with Python.

Comment: @Arthur I am not able to understand why $(2k)^3/2\pm 1$ will produce such pairs always. I am getting that you have just used $2(p+1)=n^3$, and as $n$ is even we get $p$ of that form. Is there any explanation for how we always get such pairs from $p$ of this form? Probably an argument with necessary condition, sufficient condition etc.

Comment: @OppoInfinity We don't always get a pair that way. But all pairs are of that form.

Answer (score 6):

To demonstrate that there are also huge solutions :

Define $$k=10^{100}+303593$$ $$s=4k^3-1$$ $$t=4k^3+1$$ then $(s,t)$ is a twin prime pair of the desired form which can be searched with this PARI/GP - routine

```
? z=prod(j=1,3*10^4,prime(j));k=10^100-1;gef=0;while(gef==0,k=k+1;s=4*k^3-1;t=4*
k^3+1;if(gcd(s*t,z)==1,if(ispseudoprime(s)==1,print(k-10^100);if(ispseudoprime(t)
==1,gef=1))))
```

$\ s\ $and $\ t \ $ are proven primes with $\ 301\ $ digits. Assuming the generalized bunyakovsky conjecture, there are infinite many pairs of the desired form.

Answer (score 5):

$(3,5),(107,109)$ and $(2634011,2634013)$ are only such twin prime pairs below $10^7$. You can check for more by increasing the range using this small Python code below. I just run it upto $10^8$, $(29659499,29659501)$ and $(57395627,57395629)$ are only such pairs with $10^7<p<10^8$.

---

**Edit**: 
For optimization purpose, I will use the [fact](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html) that all primes more than $3$ can be represented in the form $6k\pm 1$.

First let check manually for $p=2,3$. For $p=2$ it's clearly not possible. For $p=3$, we have $3+5=8=2^3$, so, $(3,5)$ is such pair.

Suppose, $p=6k-1$, with $p>5$, then we have $12k=n^3$. That means, $12|n^3$. But, as $n^3$ is a perfect cube, and we have $12=3\cdot 2^2$, at least $3^3\cdot 2^3=216$ will divide $n^3$. So, the pair $(108m^3-1,108m^3+1)$ will be such pair if both of them are prime.

While dealing with cubes, usually prefer to work in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, as any cube is either of $0,1,6$ in this field,i.e; $n^3\equiv 0,1,6\pmod{7}$ . So, we can have $2p+2\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, which gives $p\equiv 6\pmod{7}$, or, $2p+2\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ which implies $p\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ or $2p+2\equiv 6\pmod{7}$ which implies $p\equiv 2\pmod{7}$. Hence, only $3$ pssibilities. Here is the updated program:

```
import math
import time

start_time=time.time()
def is_prime(n):
  flag=0
  if(n==2):
    return True
  if(n%2==0):
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):
      if(n%i==0):
        flag=1
        break
    if(flag==0):
      return True
    return False 

for i in range(1,1000):#change the number inside this braket to check for larger numbers
  c=(6*i)**3 
  p=c//2-1 
  if(p%7==2 or p%7==4 or p%7==6):
    if(is_prime(p) & is_prime(p+2)):
      print(p, "is such twin prime with sum",c) 

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but my guess is that it is because your script, the substance of your answer, is quite inefficient compared to some others that were posted.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Updated it, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

$p + (p + 2) = 2p + 2 = 2(p + 1)$

For the sum to be a cube, $p + 1$ must be divisible by 4, so that the sum becomes $2 \times 4m^3$ for some integer $m$. So $p + 1$ is of the form $4m^3$.

Comment: Also, with the exception of the twin prime pair {3,5}, every pair of twin primes must be of the form {6n-1,6n+1}.  Using your notation, you can further refine based on this to $p+1=108k^3$