# $84537841287167$ and $84537841287169$ a particular pair of twin primes!

Tags: number-theory

$84537841287167$ and $84537841287169$ are a pair of twin primes.

Their sum is a cube.

Moreover, if we call Sumdigits(n) the sum of the decimal digits of n, it happens that:

Sumdigits(84537841287167)=$71$ and Sumdigits(84537841287169)=$73$, where $71$ and $73$ are another pair of twin primes. If you sum 71+73 you get 144 which is a square.

Any other example of these pairs? Any other twin pair p (the lesser of the twin pair), p+2 (the greater of the twin pair) such that $p+p+2$ is a cube and sumdigits(p) is the lesser of another twin pair and sumdigits(p)+2 is the greater of the twin pair.

Comment: @Arthur can you find another example?

Comment: Note that if $p$ ends in a $9$, then $sumdigit(p+2)\not=sumdigit(p)+2$. E.g, $p=29$ has digit sum $11$, which is the lesser of a twin prime, but $p=31$ has digit sum $4$, not $13$.

Answer (score 3):

Repurposing my program from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174436/twin-primes-whose-sum-is-a-cube/) into

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
  if n == 2:
    return True
  if n % 2 == 0:
    return False
  for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):
    if n%i==0:
        return False
  return True

def sumdigits(n):
  s = 0
  while(n > 0):
    s += n%10
    n //= 10
  return s

for i in range(1, 10000):
    for k in [30*i, 30*i + 6, 30*i + 24]:
        l = int(k**3/2 - 1)
        if is_prime(sumdigits(l)) & is_prime(sumdigits(l) + 2):
          if is_prime(l) & is_prime(l+2):
            print("%d & %d & %d\\\\" % (l, k, sumdigits(l)))
```

These are the examples I find:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
p & \sqrt[3]{p + p+2} & \text{digit sum of }p\\
\hline
2634011 & 174 & 17\\
863999999 & 1200 & 71\\
6911999999 & 2400 & 71\\
402178499999 & 9300 & 71\\
544773694499 & 10290 & 71\\
789769507067 & 11646 & 71\\
1238406988499 & 13530 & 71\\
2383539493499 & 16830 & 71\\
2555779209587 & 17226 & 71\\
3867099660287 & 19776 & 71\\
4551572735999 & 20880 & 71\\
4575155967647 & 20916 & 71\\
4934599312499 & 21450 & 71\\
5884168608467 & 22746 & 71\\
8372889188351 & 25584 & 71\\
9294282724499 & 26490 & 71\\
13777276964831 & 30204 & 71\\
14074975043999 & 30420 & 71\\
25367592203999 & 37020 & 71\\
28698158691611 & 38574 & 71\\
31346894274587 & 39726 & 71\\
33749342890847 & 40716 & 71\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
After this, examples seemed to really dry up. I didn't find any more for an hour or two, at any rate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92048/discussion-on-answer-by-arthur-84537841287167-and-84537841287169-a-particula).